# online fast computation environment for ruby

Tags: ruby, performance, amazon-ec2

I'm writing a ruby program that need raw cpu power (I know ruby is a very bad choice for this!).. but I don't have a powerful computer, so I wanted to rent something online that you pay per hour..

Any idea? Something simple to use yet very powerful, with multiple cores. I took a look at amazon ec2, that's a possibility. Anything else, more CPU oriented?

Comment: Have you looked at [RubyInline](http://www.zenspider.com/ZSS/Products/RubyInline/)? That could be used to speed up critical sections of your code.

Comment: Not clear whether you want to get 'raw cpu power' in ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as on-demand compute power, Amazon's EC2 is a good choice. You can either pay market rates or you can go to their special discount [spot market](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/) which is similar, but your instance can and will be terminated without warning when demand picks up again.

It's best to have a system that either uses a persistent EBS drive to save results, or saves them to something like S3 frequently.

If you can parallelize your processing, try and split it across the most cost-effective instance type instead of having to pay a premium for a single instance. For example, the XL Hi-CPU On-Demand Instance gives you 20 compute units for $0.68/hr. compared with the 4XL Cluster Compute Instance which is only 33.5 for $1.60/hr.

Remember that a single Ruby process can only use one CPU core unless you're using a combination of JRuby and threads. You will need to support multiple processes in order to make full use of the machine if this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleWorker](http://www.simpleworker.com/) - I think it's more simpler then EC2.